# Point buy system for a tabletop rpg

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, numericupdown

I'm trying to make a point buy system using numeric up/downs. Here's the idea:
There are six numeric up/downs, one for each trait (Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom and Charisma). Each trait begins at 10 points. You can't bring a trait below 7 or above 18.

I'm a total noob, but I managed to do this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            numericUpDown1.Maximum = 18;
            numericUpDown1.Minimum = 7;
        }
```

I did this one six times. In my form, there is now six numeric up/downs. Now I'm trying to do something which is way too much for my minuscule knowledge.

I want a system in which the value of the six numeric up downs is combined and cannot be exceeded, which means that in this case, we would have 60 points and couldn't increase any score unless we decreased one. I would add 15 points to that "Point pool", so the user doesn't have to decrease a stat straight away, in order to increase another one.

> Example: I have 1 point left, and my scores go as follows: 15, 15, 14, 10, 10, 10. I increase the third score by 1 point. I now have this:
>
> `15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10.`
>
> > Now I have nothing left, but I want my fourth score at 15 points. In order to achieve this, I have to decrease the fifth and sixth score until I have 5 points freed up. I now have this:
> >
> > `15, 15, 15, 15, 7, 8.`

Having a Lil' box in my form to display how many points are left would be a cherry on top.

I did my best to explain this. Please take note that English is not my native language and I sometimes do struggle with it.

I'm clueless as to how I can achieve this, as I barely have any knowledge of C#. What would be the code missing ?

Comment: If you call `numericUpDown1.Maximum = 18;  numericUpDown1.Minimum = 7;` on `valueChanged`, it will be executed on every change of every item. You can just set this value in designer, or vall it on `formLoaded` instead.

Comment: Can you show your aspx code?

Comment: @mikeyq6 It's tagged WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

It would easier if you create a Character class

You could define defaults for each property in constructor, and individual methods to increase or decrease its points.

```
public class Character
{
    private int totalPointsMax = 60;
    private int maxPoints = 18;
    private int minPoints = 7;

    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Dexterity { get; set; }
    public int Constitution { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public int Wisdom { get; set; }
    public int Charisma { get; set; }

    public Character()
    {
        // create new Character defaults...
        Strength = 10;
        Dexterity = 10;
        Constitution = 10;
        Intelligence = 10;
        Wisdom = 10;
        Charisma = 10;
    }

    private int GetTotalCharacterPoints()
    {
        return Strength + Dexterity + Constitution + Intelligence + Wisdom + Charisma;
    }

    //example of method to increase Strength
    public void IncreaseStrength()
    {
        int availablePoints = totalPointsMax - GetTotalCharacterPoints();
        if (availablePoints > 0 && Strength < maxPoints)
            Strength++;
    }

    //example of method to decrease Strength
    public void DecreaseStrength()
    {
        if (Strength >= minPoints)
            Strength--;
    }

    //missing the other increase/decrease methods for the rest of features...

}
```

You just need to instance at beginning and your UI buttons only need to invoke the CharacterFoo.IncreaseStrength() or CharacterFoo.DecreaseWisdom() ... etc.

Also, with this option you can allways reuse this in any part of the game.. 
(ex: if your character finds any special potion .. then CharacterFoo.IncreaseStrength() )

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do it.

Firstly, move these outside of the event function:

```
numericUpDown1.Maximum = 18;
numericUpDown1.Minimum = 7;
```

My recommendation would be to set a variable with the maximum points:

`private int MAX_POINTS = 60;`

Then when one of them is changed, you can call another method that adds up all of the current boxes, and determines whether it is over the limit or not:

```
private bool TotalOfStatsIsOverLimit() {
    int total = GetTotalOfStats();
    return total > MAX_POINTS;
}

private int GetTotalOfStats() {
    int total = 0;

    // TODO: Go through each number box and add to the total

    return total;
}

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if(TotalOfStatsIsOverLimit()) {
         // TODO: Decrease the value of the stat box that was updated
    }

}
```

One advantage of doing it this way, is that you can reuse the same event method `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` for all 6 of your stat boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would go with a class for character since it will greatly simplify your future works, though if you are new, it may be harder at the start.
Still, you can follow up the basic approach as follows:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int totalPoints = 60 + 15; // sum of each trait plus the pool bonus

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            if (control is NumericUpDown)
            {
                NumericUpDown numControl = control as NumericUpDown;
                numControl.Minimum = 7;
                numControl.Maximum = 18;
                numControl.Value = 10;
                numControl.ValueChanged += nud_ValueChanged;
                lblPointsLeft.Text = "15"; // bonus points
            }
        }
    }

    private void nud_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = (int)(nudCha.Value + nudCon.Value + nudDex.Value + nudInt.Value + nudStr.Value + nudWis.Value);
        int pointsLeft = totalPoints - sum;
        NumericUpDown nudSender = (NumericUpDown)sender;

        if (pointsLeft < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No points left");
            // restore last change
            // undo the last change 

            nudSender.Value = nudSender.Value - 1;
            pointsLeft++;



        }
        lblPointsLeft.Text = pointsLeft.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Pseudocode:
You want to create a variable to hold your current points.  Create some labels to hold that variable, and make sure you do AJAX calls, otherwise every time you update you are going to be calling this from the server again.  This is probably better done in Javascript/Jquery.

```
int pointsUsed = numericUpDown1.value + numericUpDown2.value + numericUpDown6.value; //add all 6 of your values.

//for your textbox:
label1.text = "points left is:" 
label2.text = 75 - pointsUsed;

private void checkBox1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{//to add points
   if (pointsUsed < 75)
   {
      numericUpDown1.Value += 1;
      pointsUsed += 1;
   }
}
```

Check [MSDN NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.